# php salt authentication

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, salt

Thank you for your honest criticism towards my ignorance in php/mysql and I appreciate your help concerning this issue.

After making the corrections suggested below I'm running into the issue where the registered

```
sha1(md5($password).$salt)
```

is not === when compared to the login authentication

```
sha1(md5($password).$row['salt']);
```

So I created a script to see what the login script was seeing and it compares the two.

```
 $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `form_password` = '$encrypted'  WHERE `username` = '$username'";  
     mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

password is registered as "1fcb4bdeb8a98151f5f74a2af0b5045ec277c501"

and being called back as  "f2c04d2583f111fcd41288dc75901f6c870cfc6b"

Here is the updated script on login:

```
else {  

$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);


$sql  =  "SELECT `password`, `salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (is_resource($result) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $row        =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $encrypted  =   sha1(md5($password).$row['salt']);

     if($encrypted === $row['password']){
    header('Location: page3.php');
    exit;
     } else{

     $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `form_password` = '$encrypted'  WHERE `username` = '$username'";  
     mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    header('Location: page2.php');
    exit;
     }
} else{
header('Location: page4.php');
exit;
}
}
```

Comment: When it comes to security, "learning the hard way" is definitely the wrong way.

Comment: `sha1(md5())`?  What makes you think that combining two weak hashes results in anything other than a weak hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) How large is your password field in the database? SHA1 hashes are 40 characters long, so if you've got a field size less than that, your hashed password will be truncated.

b) Putting `or die()` on your `$sql = ...` line is pointless. Creating a string is extraordinarily unlikely to fail. You need to put the `or die()` on the line where the query is actually executed:

```
$sql = "..."
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(...);
```

c) Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, as you paste the user-provided username and password directly into your queries without escaping.

d) You don't check if the query to get the user's pw/salt succeeds. If the username is incorrect, the query will retrieve no rows. This isn't an error condition, as the query did what it was supposed to. You need to check, via `mysql_num_rows($result)` if the query did return a row or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are quoting your column identifiers incorrectly. Use backticks or nothing at all.

```
SELECT 'salt' FROM table WHERE ....
```

Will return "salt". Use instead:

```
SELECT `salt` ....
```

or

```
SELECT salt ....
```

Please also consider the points that Marc B made. They are all good and valid.

Comment: Good catch, I'd missed that. This'll definitely screw up the function since he'll get a constant `password` and `salt` instead of the stored pw/salt values.

Comment: Also, if you felt like and if you have your mysql server configured to do this, you can quote identifiers using double quotes. This isn't default behavior but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

*You have got so many things wrong there.*

#### Here is your working code:

*The db password is encrypted as:*

```
<?php
function generateSalt(){
    // Declare $salt
    $salt = '';

    // And create it with random chars
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
        $salt .= chr(rand(48, 57)) . chr(rand(65, 90)) . chr(rand(97, 122));
    }

    return $salt;
}
$salt       =   generateSalt();
$encrypted  =   sha1(md5($password).$salt);
$query      =   "INSERT INTO `users`(`password`, `salt`) VALUES '$encrypted', '$salt')";
?>
```

*index. php*

```
<?php
function salt() {
    // Declare $salt
    $salt = '';
    
    // And create it with random chars
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
        $salt .= chr(rand(48, 57)) . chr(rand(65, 90)) . chr(rand(97, 122));
    }
    
    return $salt;
 }
 
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 

$sql        =   "SELECT `password`, `salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 0,1";
$result     =   mysql_query($sql) or die('Could not access user.');
if(is_resource($result) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $row        =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $encrypted  =   sha1(md5($password).$row['salt']);

    if($encrypted === $row['password']){
        header('Location: page3.php');
        exit;
    } else{
        header('Location: page2.php');
        exit;
    }
} else{
    header('Location: page2.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do this in pseudo-code

```
$salt='secretword';// that do not change
$encrypted=sha1($password.$salt);

INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES($username, $encrypted);
```

later

```
//get $username and $password from user input
$encrypted=sha1($password.$salt);
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$encrypded' LIMIT 1
```

note encrypting should be done in php because MySQL will calculate SHA1(..) for each row when matching and is unnecessary waste